# Connecting SQL with Windows form application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect my form application with SQL client. When I am trying to connect by clicking data---->add new data Source=--->New Connection  and I selected the Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient) and selected my database named dish_Tv.mdf. After selecting I clicked the Test Connection button it says

> User instance login flag is not supported on this version of sql
>   server.the connection will be closed.

Can anyone help me out solving this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, the language is named "C#" not "CSharp", and the name doesn't need to be in the title - it belongs in the tags like you've got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2005(Full Version) does not support the "user instance"(automatic creation of databases from code) directive in the connection string.  Its a feature of sql server express edition.

May be following thread will help you

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=609077&SiteID=1

http://forums.asp.net/t/913172.aspx?PageIndex=2

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/0738cb01-106f-4376-b92d-a977a022ece8

Comment: the sql server which i am using is 2008 R2.I am trying to connect from Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2008 Express edition.Whether it is possible to connect c# express to sql 2008.